# Makumba Config - Do not include JS/CSS

Tags: makumba

While working on a bootstrap implementation for Karamba! I get many conflicts from Makumba's default JS library prototype, which is conflicting with the one bootstrap is using - jQuery.

Is there a way to tell Makumba to not include it's Javascript files and libraries, as we any want to use our own JS?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for now:
It seems that Makumba searches for the `<head>` and `</head>`tags and inserts its javascript and css files right after or before them.
to avoid this, i added an attribute to these tags:

```
<head attr>
  ...
</head attr>
```